# Is Interop.Outlook multithreaded?

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

I need to use [Outlook](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:en.wikipedia.org+Outlook&num=%i&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) [Interop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop) objects for generating .MSG files from a web interface. That's why they will be accessed simultaneously by different threads. Is it multithreaded?

And another question: Does Outlook need to be initialized (e.g. account set) before using `Outlook.Application` on a server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **No**.

Don't go down the automation route, Office applications are not designed to be used within a non-user interactive environment or to be ran on a server. Microsoft have posted quite a long knowledge base **[article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)** on this detailing problems from security, scalability etc.

Previously this hasn't been a problem and people have gotten away with it, just ignoring the advice. However you'll find that the newer operating systems (vista/server 2k8/win7) and new versions of Office simply don't work anymore. I highly recommend not going down that route.

Comment: +1:  A component at my office went down this route a decade or more ago.  The poor people in charge of maintaining it still regularly run into problems that can be either directly or indirectly attributable to running office via non-interactive automation.  And that's just doing it via Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know none of the Office API's were designed to work on the server side, only at the client side.

Comment: what is better way of creating '.msg' file? Using IStorage interface?

Comment: Redemption might be able to help you out here, or have you thought about EWS exchange dav?