# Alternative to outlook interop api for receiving an email

Tags: email, interop, outlook

I have an email account on a remote server.
I created an application that utilizes outlook interop api to search for an email with specific subject than extract an attachment from it and save it to a directory.

Everything is fine when I run that application manually.
But when I create a scheduled task for this application, I get

```
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(System.RuntimeType, System.Object[], Boolean)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)
   at PocketDataFromEmail.EmailManager..ctor()
   at MyApp.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

It is said that outlook is not suitable for that kind of scenarios:
[Is Interop.Outlook multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176966/is-interop-outlook-multithreaded)

Any ideas on how to check the inbox of an exchange account and extract attachments without using outlook interop api?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would Exchange Web Services be an option?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045.aspx

There is also MAPI, though it is older technology, and I recall it wasn't that fun to use:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, it is suitable to use Exchange Web Services, as mentioned by PeskyGnat above, as it does not require MS Outlook to be installed on the machine.

You may also have a look at Aspose.Network for .NET component, a commercial API, than can get messages from Exchange, Imap and Pop3 mail servers with full attachments. Please refer to http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/saving-messages-from-exchange-server-mailbox-in-eml-and-msg-format.html for some sample code to read messages from Exchange Server.

Disclosure: I work as a Technical Evangelist at Aspose.